# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) on project

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to get exploded war file from Maven run .
Having one parent project (MyApp) and two other project one for ORM (MyApp-Orm), one for view part (MyApp-Web) which is dependent on parent project for build.
i.e 
MyApp
   
     MyApp-Orm
   
     MyApp-Web

When trying to run maven install getting below Exception : - `Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) on project MyApp-Web: The packaging for this project did not assign a file to the build artifact`

 My Pom.xml are : -

1) MyApp -- pom.xml

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>MyApp</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyApp</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>MyApp</name>
  <description>MyApp</description>
  --- different dependencies---  
  <build>
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-war</id>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>war-exploded</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exploded</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
</build>
```

2) MyApp-Web -- pom.xml

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>MyApp</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>MyApp-Web</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>MyApp Web</name> 

  --- different dependencies---
    <build>
        <finalName>MyApp Web</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <compilerVersion>1.7</compilerVersion>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
  </build>
```

3) MyApp-Orm -- pom.xml

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>MyApp</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>MyApp-Orm</artifactId>
  <name>MyApp Orm</name>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  --- different dependencies---

  <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <compilerVersion>1.7</compilerVersion>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <finalName>MyApp Orm</finalName>
    </build>
```

Am i missing any configuration in any of pom?

Comment: The maven-install-plugin needs the war file. You are telling maven-war-plugin to generate only the war-exploded **directory**, set the ```none``` phase to ```package``` in the ```default-war``` execution to generate both.

Comment: Follow the conventions over configuration which you are violating here. Just define the maven-war-plugin exactly once in your MyApp POm file in pluginManagement to define the version. And in your other pom's you only define the packaging `war` nothing else..Also define the maven-compiler-pugin with it's configuration in the parent where you defined the maven-war-plugin ...